# Android: Why are methods for getting neighboring cell signal strengths better than those for current cell signal strength?

Tags: android, rssi

I'm writing an android application that collects cell signal strengths.  I am having trouble getting the "current" cell signal strength, but I don't have any problem getting the "neighboring" cell signal strengths.

To get the current cell signal strength, I created a PhoneStateListener and implemented the onSignalStrengthChanged callback.  It works, but not very well.  It seems like the signal strength hardly ever changes, and resolution jumps to only a few numbers.  I would accept the answer that the resolution of the signal strength hardware is coarse, but when I use the TelephonyManager's getNeighboringCellInfo() method, it works much better.  The signal strength readings from neighboring cells change frequently, and they have much better resolution.

So, how can I get the current cell signal strength in the same way that I am getting the neighboring cell strengths?  It seems odd to me that the functionality of the neighboring cells is better than the current cell.  Am I missing something here?

I would also like to directly call a method from the telephony manager to get current cell strength, as opposed to a listener, if possible.  If anyone knows how, please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on Android 1.5 sources (BatteryStatsImpl.java) notification is being sent only if signal changes between following  states:

```
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_NONE_OR_UNKNOWN (99)
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GREAT (16-32)
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GOOD (8-15)
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_MODERATE (4-7)
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_POOR (0-3)
```

So in your case signal strength changes within the same range and you don't receive notifications.

I guess it is done this way to save battery life.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method is not working very well because as written in the javadoc, [`onSignalStrengthChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onSignalStrengthChanged(int)) is deprecated since api 2.0, and replaced by `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` (note the "s"), but unfortunatly this method is private !

There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4968) about that, it seems google has removed the method for unknow reason (maybe because its not working well as you have noticed it), and it will be available in a next sdk release.

You just have to be patient then and vote [here](http://moderator.appspot.com/#15/e=120951&t=11fd95) to speed up dev process !