# Get Cell RSSI(Network Signal Strength) on Android 1.5

Tags: java, android, signal-strength

Is there any way to retrieve the current cellular Signal Strength (RSSI) on Android 1.5?

I know there's a way to listen for signal strength updates through the `TelephonyManager`, but this seems to only give a "state," not a numeric value.

Is using the RSSI field on a neighboring cell fairly accurate?  I'm guessing not, but I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TelephonyManager.listen with flag LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

Comment: I'm attempting to wire in a listener service for this (and other broadcast information - like battery) right now.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: So how did it go? and if you success please past here(i`am using android 1.5)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some kind of API change between the Android Versions.
The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011543/android-why-are-methods-for-getting-neighboring-cell-signal-strengths-better-tha) should give you some points to look further into this.

Comment: Yes, I saw this post, but that person indicated that the information was not accurate, but I was not sure in what way it was not accurate.  I would take kind-of right information over no information at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that uses a PhoneStatuslistener.
Is a learn be example tutorial, it help me when I was programming.

http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/

Adrian.