# Android Antena Data?

Tags: android

How do I acces how strong my signal is for an android phone? I am new to android programming but have experience in java, and C#. I would like to be able to tell how strong my antena signal is with a numerical value if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question, [Get Cell RSSI(Network Signal Strength) on Android 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275712/get-cell-rssinetwork-signal-strength-on-android-1-5) was asked about a similar issue and the answer provided, 
"TelephonyManager.listen with flag LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html"
was accepted.