# get current SignalStrengths android

Tags: android

I want to get current Signal Strengths in android device on any button click.
I have written this

```
public static int getSignal(Context c) {
    class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        int signal;

        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            signal = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
        }
    }
    TelephonyManager Tel;
    MyPhoneStateListener MyListener;
    MyListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    Tel = (TelephonyManager) c.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    return MyListener.signal;
}
```

code but it always returns me 0

Please somebody tell me how to get current Signal Strengths.

Answer (score 2):

> code but it always return me 0

Of course. `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` will not have been called yet. And, you stop listening with your `LISTEN_NONE` line, so you will probably never

> Please any body tell me how to get current Signal Strengths.

You will get the signal strength in `onSignalStrengthsChanged()`, once a change has been detected in the signal strength, if you get rid of the `LISTEN_NONE` line. Only use `LISTEN_NONE` when you are done with the listener.

Comment: there's no way to get the current signal strength right now? What if I don't want to wait an undeterminate amount of time to wait for the onSignalStrengthsChanged() to do something ?

Comment: Pls if you find the solution tell me?

Comment: Hmm - as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3889407/281545) `after registering PhoneStateListener you will have instant notification`. Still your answer [should be valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888775/instant-signal-strength/3889407#comment4143475_3890419)